# Why does Huawei Netcube appear as DNS server to a MacBook

Tags: networking, macos, dns, nat

I'm operating a MacBook (with macOS 10.13.6) at home. My internet connection is thru a Huawei Netcube E5180s-22.

When I inquire my DNS configuration with `scutil --dns` I get this (`192.168.8.1` is the private IP address of the NetCube on the WLAN):

```
resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.8.1
  nameserver[1] : 192.168.8.1
```

Now I am wondering: does the NetCube run some kind of DNS server, or is this report an artifact of it performing NAT (or similar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an artifact of NAT. Routers typically run a simple forwarding DND proxy - very often based on dnsmasq. One reason is that the ISPs Nameserver is often given to the router when the connection to the ISP is established. - which may be after the computer has requested it's DHCP lease (which rivides the DNS info to the computer as well), so it might not know this info at the time it needs to give it to the PC.

(Note that DNS can be natted like most other requests + which you can rove for yourself by manually setting 8.8.8.8 in your PC.

Comment: Additionally, advertising itself as the DNS server lets it handle hostnames such as "router" that resolve to the router itself for its web-based configuration.